# How to filter a list for a letter followed by two numbers?

Tags: python

I have a list of some strings. For example:

```
df = ['N01', 'N02', 'S02', 'ST3', 'N99', 'NSR', 'S43', 'ASF', 'HTF', 'S78']
```

I need to retrieve the values of N and S followed by two numbers. So N01 up-to N99 and S01 up-to S99.

The output needed is:

```
res = ["N01", "N02", "S02", "N99", "S43", "S78"]
```

Comment: What do you mean 'filter'? What is your expected input and output? What have you tried?

Comment: Is there always a leading number -> remove the first character. If not, give an example how your input looks like.

Comment: @white

For example:

I need to filter for N01 to N99 and S01 to S99.

Eg:

df = ['N01','N02','S02','ST3','N99','NSR','S43','ASF','HTF','S78']

The output needed is N01,N02,S02,N99,S43,S78

I need to retrieve the values of N and S with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to check if the string matches your requirement. A regex for this case would be:

```
[NS]\d\d
```

You can then use a list comprehension to filter the matching strings from the input list:

```
res = [s for s in df if re.fullmatch(r"[NS]\d\d", s)]
```